# How to interpret SyntaxError: Unexpected token (?:?), raisedAt:?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I do not remember making any significant changes to my code but suddenly it stopped working. Specifically bringing up the login screen fails.

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const passport = require('passport');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Login (get)');
    let msg = (req.usrMsg === null && typeof(req.usrMsg) !== "undefined")?req.usrMsg:"";
    console.log('msg:',msg);
    res.render('login', { 
            title: 'Login',
            message: msg
        });
});
```

The console logs are printed but then I get: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token (141:0) ... raisedAt: 6745`
This particular file login.js does not contain anywhere near 141 lines so which file should I consider to look at?

The error message continues as such:

```
{ SyntaxError: Unexpected token (141:0)
    at Parser.pp.raise (D:\Code\ghdb\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:943:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (D:\Code\ghdb\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1503:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (D:\Code\ghdb\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:327:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (D:\Code\ghdb\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:216:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (D:\Code\ghdb\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:197:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (D:\Code\ghdb\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:151:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (D:\Code\ghdb\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:133:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (D:\Code\ghdb\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:110:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExpression (D:\Code\ghdb\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:86:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement (D:\Code\ghdb\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1750:23)
  pos: 6744,
  loc: Position { line: 141, column: 0 },
  raisedAt: 6745 }
```

How can I actually find the token which is unexpected?

Thank you,
Jens

Comment: Is this file being required in some other file ?

Comment: It is required in `app.js`: `var loginRouter = require('./routes/login');`

Comment: If your file does not contain that many lines, it is a good indicator that the problem occurs in the npm modules you have installed. Since you haven't made any changes, it might be because of a new version being released. Can you remove the `^` from the version numbers of the three modules in your `package.json`, delete `node_modules`, rerun `npm i` and see if the problem persists?

Comment: These packages do not have the `^` in the package.json

Comment: usrMsg = null ?

Comment: Good point, changed to: `let msg = (req.usrMsg === null || typeof(req.usrMsg) === "undefined")?"":req.usrMsg;`. Unfortunately, doesn't affect the problem.

Comment: what does `console.log('msg:',msg);` print? edit: also, does the error occur as you run the app, or does it throw error when you try to `GET /` ?

Comment: The error is thrown upon reaching `res.render`. msg prints just fine ... as expected.

Comment: `req.usrMsg === null && typeof(req.usrMsg) !== "undefined"` The second condition seems redundant. If it's null... it isn't undefined. but that's unrelated to your problem.

Comment: Are you sure the request data isn't invalid?